# SystemBack - Are frequent Updates Normal?

Tags: backup

I have SystemBack ver. 1.1.3.110 (etc) installed on my PC, running Ubuntu 14.04.

I've noticed that almost every time there are updates for my OS and programs, there is an update for SystemBack.

It requires more "updates" than any other program on my computer, by far. This has me a bit concerned. I appreciate programs being kept up-to-date.

Is SystemBack "stable"?
Does it refrain from secret "data mining"?

Comment: Is the version number raising after update? Are you sure, the update is installed successfully?

Comment: Version number goes up after update. I've been hesitant to use the program, given my concerns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data mining? If you're using regular tools to update like `apt` that's basically just your computer downloading files.

I'm not familiar with SystemBack to know what it should & shouldn't do, but this looks like [it's launchpad page](https://launchpad.net/~nemh/+archive/ubuntu/systemback) if you'd like to browse the source code.

There *should* be a changelog somewhere to see when the last updates were, there could've been a bunch released close together recently.

I think I found it, https://code.launchpad.net/~nemh/systemback/devel does show 5 updates this month, and 5 more in the last 2 days of November.

Or I thought I saw a "daily" branch that likely gets updated more frequently, you could be in too. You might want to switch to the ["systemback/stable" branch](https://code.launchpad.net/~nemh/systemback/stable) it seems to have less frequent updates and would hopefully be more stable, but I'm not sure if those are in a Ubuntu PPA.

Comment: Thanks, that was very useful information and links. I'm currently using version 1.1.3_110_12.08.2014. So, I guess everything is ok.

Comment: No problem. I think there's a logfile somewhere of what's been installed, maybe with the date too, not sure if it's from apt or dpkg or the auto updater. But if the answer's been useful & seems like the best one, feel free to select it as correct / check-mark it :)